# how to diynamic checkbox from database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

can i create a dynamic/flexible checkbox from a table?
my table structure like this :

```
| id | category |
  1    School
  2    Hospital
  3    Police
```

my checkbox html :

```
 <input name="checkbox1" onclick="showPOI1($(this));" value="1" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />School<br>
    <input name="checkbox2" onclick="showPOI2($(this));" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />Hospital <br>
    <input name="checkbox3" onclick="showPOI3($(this));" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />Police <br>
```

and javascript function for each checkbox like this :

```
        window.showPOI1 = function(t) {
            if (t.is(':checked')) {
                //alert('checked');
                for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    if (markers[i].category == 1) { //--> i want compare category from database, not hardcode
                        markers[i].setVisible(true);
                        markers[i].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);


                    }

                }

            } else {
                infowindow.close();
                for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    if (markers[i].category == 1) {
                        markers[i].setVisible(false);
                    }

                }
            }

        }




        window.showPOI2 = function(t) {
            if (t.is(':checked')) {
                //alert('checked');
                for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    if (markers[i].category == 2) {//--> i want compare category from database, not hardcode
                        markers[i].setVisible(true);
                        markers[i].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);
                    }

                }

            } else {
                infowindow.close();
                for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    if (markers[i].category == 2) {
                        markers[i].setVisible(false);
                    }

                }
            }

        }



        window.showPOI3 = function(t) {
            if (t.is(':checked')) {

                for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    if (markers[i].category == 3) {//--> i want compare category from database, not hardcode
                        markers[i].setVisible(true);
                        markers[i].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);
                    }

                }

            } else {
                infowindow.close();
                for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    if (markers[i].category == 3) {
                        markers[i].setVisible(false);
                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

i have 2 problems here. first, i want to create checkbox based on table. checkbox value from id column and its caption from category column. then, i want to send the value to javascript function. the second problem is, can i create dynamic function too based on table? is it possible? or do you have another idea? how to creat dynamic checkbox and javascript function from table.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: You need to query the table then output the results to the DOM as you want them.

Comment: i used codeigniter, i was query the table and pass the value to the view as $data['category'].

Comment: Okay, and what happens when you output that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this, You can create dynamic checkbox by using database and pass the id to javascript function on onclick the checkbox. It may help you.

```
<?php
$i=0;
foreach($category as $row){
$i++; 
?> 
    <input name="checkbox[]" 
            onclick="showPOI1(<?php echo 'checkbox'.$i; ?>);" 
            value="<?php echo $row['category']; ?>" type="checkbox" 
            id="<?php echo 'checkbox'.$i; ?>" />

    <?php echo $row['category']; ?>

<?php 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, i will try soon. btw, every checkbox has a function. when i add a checkbox, how can i create a function too? or you have advice or idea for me?

Comment: Here while click any checkbox it will go to the function of  showPOI1 with the argument of id. you can use the id of the particular checkbox and do what ever calculation you want.

Comment: Hai Mani, i want ask something, if I used showPOI1($(this));, can i get these checkbox value?

Comment: we are passing the id name to that function. so you can retrive by using some variable like function showPOI1(idname){ }. Inside that you can get the value by using id like $("#"+idname).